# http.client get a 404 error

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x

I am trying to make a GET request from a cgi file using the http.client from python, but I still get the 404 status code.

The file is accessible, executable and I can access using the browser, but using the python client I get the 404 code.

My code:

```
conn = client.HTTPConnection(args.domain)
conn.request('GET', '/cgi_bin/cgi.py', headers={
    'Connection': "Keep-Alive",
    'Accept': ' text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
})
status = conn.getresponse().status
conn.close()
```

the cgi test file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n\ntest_cgi")
```

When I use the explorer I get the correct response (test_cgi) and the 200 OK, but when I use the http.client apache2 throws a 404 status.

the apache log access:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2016:04:20:25 -0400] "GET /cgi-bin/cgi.py HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2016:04:20:37 -0400] "GET /cgi_bin/cgi.py HTTP/1.1" 404 465 "-" "-"
```

Any idea why this happens?